# 'require': no such file to load — spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I just reinstalled the the OS and installed Ruby/Rails with RVM. But when I try to run Rspec tests I get an error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
```

I generated spec_helper file with command: `rails g rspec:install`

I have the spec_helper file under the spec directory.
Does anyone knows why it isn't working?

The error appears only when I am running tests from sublime text 2. I have added the tests like in this link: https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests

My Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'rspec-rails'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Do you have any spec files in subdirectories of the normal spec folders, or is there anything else that could be unusual about your spec directory layout?

Comment: I generated integration test, tried to run and got this error in sublime. When I run rspec spec from command line, the tests work! But they don't work in Sublime and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you looked at the additional features section and tried those settings? https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests#additional-features

Comment: Yes, I did. Still nothing works. I have installed this way Rails and Rspec about three times before (on Virtual Box) and never had this kind of problems. I don't know whats wrong now!

Comment: Really? No one knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Sublime Text 2 from command line

```
$ cd "to your app folder then"

$ subl .
```

This should work and they have it as Note in  https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests